# Do httpd/conf.d/* files override httpd.conf

Tags: web-server, httpd, apache2, httpd.conf

If there is different configuration for the same parameter in both `conf/httpd.conf` and a `/conf.d/*` file, which will take precedence?

I can’t find this explicitly stated in any official documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not in the official documentation, because it is configuration specific.
If you look at `conf/httpd.conf` you'll notice an `Include` directive that includes the files in `conf.d/*`

The resulting configuration is what is in `httpd.conf` with the content of every file in `conf.d` (in alphabetic order) added where the `Include` directive is.

Comment: To add to this: Subsequent statements will override prior ones so the last one (in the parsed order explained by Andreas) will take precedence.